# How to set timeout for headless chrome

Tags: node.js, macos, google-chrome-headless

I try:

`chrome --timeout 15000 .....`

And if chrome doesn't finish in 15 seconds it should finish immediately.

But when i run

`chrome --headless --disable-gpu --timeout 30000 --dump-dom http://example.com`

I get

> [1110/120048.838007:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(603)] Open multiple tabs
>   is only supported when remote debugging is enabled.

It works w/o --timeout flag

Chrome Canary v64
OSX

> **Update at 2019 Nov.**
>
> I noticed this question gets a consistent flow of views and still
>   provides no to little value. I wanted to update that now I use
>   puppeteer, which is project from Google itself to use headless Chrome
>   with NodeJs and it's really easy and straight forward API. If you are
>   OK to use NodeJs - check it.
>
> https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: @griffith_joel Ubuntu or OS X + Chrome. No libraries. Just headless chrome CLI

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `chrome --headless --disable-gpu —-timeout=30000 --dump-dom http://example.com`

Answer (score 2):

You need to place the `--timeout` flag before the `--headless` flag

```
chrome --timeout 30000 --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Working only with = on macOs

```
chrome --timeout=30000 --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom http://example.com
```